# Angular CLI assets folder not going into dist folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

We have an Angular 6 universal application. My application suddenly started giving an error. Actually assets folder is not going into dist after production build. It was working properly, but suddenly assets folder is not copied into dist folder .

Please help what may be the case ?

Comment: Can you please add your `angular.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

> You use the `assets` array inside the build target in `angular.json` to list files or folders you want to copy as-is when building your project. if you think you need to exclude files, consider not putting that thing in the `assets`

First i will i have an updated project using `angular cli 6.x.x`. Then Adjust your assets paths into your `angular.json` like this:

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/manifest.json",
    "src/ngsw-worker-mod.js",
    "src/sitemap.xml",
    "src/robots.txt",
    "src/sitemap_video.xml"
],
```

Then make sure you never try to copy a file outside the project output path.

**Second method**
If you really want to use the `glob` method from  [node glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob), i think you will need make sure it's installed like in the documentation explained.

You can take a look in the [official documentation of assets angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md)

Answer (score 0):

below is my angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular.io-example": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/ngsw-worker-mod.js",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap_video.xml"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        },
        "app-shell": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:app-shell",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular.io-example:build",
            "serverTarget": "angular.io-example:server",
            "route": "app-shell-path"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "angular.io-example-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "cli": {},
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular.io-example:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {},
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if it can be help you, but my angular.json assets is like

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
```

there no "input" and "output". Angular-cli: 6.1.3, Node 10.5.0